# RCT-Folly-Build-Detox-React-Native

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, detox

Error:
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Path/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/i386/F14Table.o /Path/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/container/detail/F14Table.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Pre-Condition:

- Follow the setup detox latest version
- detox build --configuration iOS file.ts

-Environment (please complete the following information):

- Detox: ^19.6.5
- React Native: 0.67.4
- Node:v16.16.0
- Device: Iphone 13 simulator
- Xcode: 13.4.1 (13F100)
- iOS: 15.0
- macOS: Monterey
- jest: 28.1.2

Comment: Can you post your Podfile? Also are you using an M1 Mac?

Comment: If possible may be worth trying an earlier RN version too

Answer (score 2):

Had to add `"-UseModernBuildSystem=YES -arch x86_64"` to the build settings step to resolve.

Comment: Explicitly specifying the architecture with `-arch x86_64` resolved the issues I was having, thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly did you add it?

Comment: In `.detoxrc.js`, append to the end of the build commands.